# How do I make my own customized Ubuntu version?

Tags: customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)

Is there any GUI tool for that?