# Build a custom Ubuntu based distribution

Tags: grub2, wubi, custom-distributions, customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make my own customized Ubuntu version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773/how-do-i-make-my-own-customized-ubuntu-version)

I am working on making a custom Ubuntu 11.10 based distro.(64 bit)
I am adding non open source packages, replacing packages, changed user interface from Unity to GNOME, and more changes.
My system is ready, and I want to create a redistributable image for my distro.
When you go to system settings -> system info, you see a logo with the Ubuntu name and logo, but I want to change it to the name and logo of my distro.
Also, in the boot menu, I want to change the boot entry names, and the GRUB background.
And I want to change the name Ubuntu from every possible location.
Also, I will be sharing it with people, so I want to make my own software repositories, like linux mint has, or any other distro has, I will purchase server space for that.
Also, the I want to customize the wubi installer like linux mint did and if some uses the customized tool to install my distro from Windows, they should see the name of my distro in add or remove programs page.
Any help will be appreciated!