# applications to create custom distribution of ubuntu

Tags: custom-distributions

Im looking for a application that I can use to make my own distribution of ubuntu 12.04,

Things I want in is latest updates,
applications downloaded like:
 ubuntu tweak, my unity, virtualbox, VLC, docky, twitter etc.
library codex for music and video
Nvidia Drivers

I tried out Build-Ubuntu the iso fails on the install (something boot file missing) and each time I tried making a distribution it keeps downloading things, i don't have the cap or speed to keep doing this every time i want to make distribution.

I tried installing novo-builder, did the install but cant find the application after the install.

This will help a lot with reinstall on a pc with no internet, and for giving to friends that would like to try ubuntu without the hassle to install every time.

and please don't close the answer account of duplication I tried this [Build a custom Ubuntu based distribution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114750/build-a-custom-ubuntu-based-distribution)
followed all the links and this did not work for me. The version of ubuntu builder used there is not the one I use, as I said, I cant download things evry time i make a distro

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html)?

A small excerpt about what you can do with this tool:

> Remastersys is a tool that can be used to do 2 things with an existing Klikit or Ubuntu or derivative installation.It can make a full system backup including personal data to a live cd or dvd that you can use anywhere and install. It can make a distributable copy you can share with friends. This will not have any of your personal user data in it.

Comment: So this application will allow me to make a custom ubuntu install disk that will include applications that I wish too include with distro with the latest updates in the system? Will I have to download files each time I wish to make a new distro?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.
And yes, you will need to be online, from the first link:

IMPORTANT NOTE: You must be connected to the internet so remastersys can download the correct Ubiquity frontend and it's dependencies.  If you do not have internet access when you start remastersys, it will fail to download the frontend for the installer and your live system will not be installable.

Answer (score 0):

### Ubuntu Builder

Ubuntu Builder is a simple tool to build your own distribution. It allows to download, extract, customize in many ways and rebuild your ubuntu images. You can customize i386 and amd64 images.

It is designed for Ubuntu and for its official derivates. However, any distribution based on Ubuntu may be customizable with it.

[image]

You can install Ubuntu Builder by downloading the latest version package and installing it with gdebi, ubuntu software center or dpkg. You can also use the subversion repository.

[Downloads can be found here](http://code.google.com/p/ubuntu-builder/downloads/list)

Comment: I included this answer because it worked for me. I understand the OP had issues with it.  Maybe there is a question for AU about the issues with this and other applications tried that we can resolve here.

Comment: Can I Create ubuntu server disc with GUI (gnome or unity ) using Ubuntu builder ?

Comment: Well that’s a completely different question and you should consider asking it as a separate one here at AU.  Heres the Ubuntu Builder home page and wiki etc.  http://code.google.com/p/ubuntu-builder/