# Making Customized Distro of Ubuntu Server (minimal)

Tags: 12.04, server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make my own customized Ubuntu version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773/how-do-i-make-my-own-customized-ubuntu-version)

I've made an Ubuntu installation from minimal with no X - everything is based on CLI and added some apps to it. I've custom designed it so it can be like a LAN-based web server and serve the apps/data as necessary.

I'm now trying to make a distro of this setup and tried with Remastersys. While the process completed OK and he LiveCD works well, the install option does nothing more than booting it in LiveCD mode.

One of the lines I see while Remastersys is in the process,

Installing the Ubiquity GTK frontend
grep: /etc/x11/default-display-manager: No such file or directory

I even tried removing Remastersys followed by a reinstall with no luck. "Bing*ed*" around for some help and cam across some interesting stuff which says Ubuntu does not have CLI based install process so it's not Remastersys's fault. Some suggestion was that I install ubiquity-frontend-debconf before installing Remastersys. I even tried this but no luck.

I do not need any graphical installer and there's no options to choose from at the time of install.

I don't understand why they say Ubuntu can only install with a graphical installer, when Ubuntu Server minimal edition does not seem to use a graphical installer (correct me if I'm wrong, pls)

How would I be able to go about with this, pls?

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization) wiki from official Ubuntu Documentation

Your option is alternate cd

Comment: ouch, isn't there an easier method? I came across Relinux and Systemimager. Looks like Relinux being built on Remastersys would face the same issue. I'm not sure about Systemimager (still doing some reading)

Comment: try ubuntu customization kit `sudo apt-get install uck`

Comment: or try  NOVO `sudo apt-get install novo-builder`

Comment: Thanks Kamil, I'm taking a look at NOVO as it seems a bit easier, but I'm seeing the distro building process is GUI based? Can I use NOVO BUILDER with CLI?